# Measuring GPU time from managed code

Tags: xna, monogame, sharpdx

To measure CPU code, I use a Stopwatch. Using a Stopwatch in the Draw method is meaningless for the GPU side of things since the CPU and the GPU run asynchronously.

The questions is simple: Is it possible to measure the total time spent on a chunk of HLSL code? Perhaps as granular as the technique/pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using DirectX, so you can probably use the techniques described in [this article](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2011/10/12/gpu-profiling-101/).  It explains how to use [ID3D11Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476578.aspx) objects to profile GPU code.

Since you're in managed code, you might have to use some clever [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) to get to that API if SharpDX doesn't expose the functions itself, although [it seems like it does](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-direct3d11-query).